# Bootstrap form-control and jquery popup plugin

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, validation

I have a problem using in the Bootstrap form-control AND [jQuery modal popup plugin](http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Responsive-Accessible-jQuery-Modal-Plugin-Popup-Overlay/) at the same time.

Here is the code, first my HTML form :

```
<form id="signup" class="form-inline">
   <div class="form-group">
      <input name="email" id="mailchimp_email" type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="your email">
   </div>
   <button class="theme_button my_popup_open">Discuss</button>
   <div id="response"></div>
</form>
```

It works perfectly and if the mail is not `*@*.*`, I get the classic tooltip error message. But when I had my JS code trigger the popup on the "Discuss" button, my popup works fine but there is no more Bootstrap form control...

Here is the code in my JS file which triggers the popup (very simple):

```
jQuery('#my_popup').popup();
```

My popup in the HTML file (I don't think it's revelant)

```
<div id="my_popup" style="background-color:white; opacity:1;">
   test
   <button class="my_popup_close">Close</button>

</div>
```

Can I let the Bootstrap control form, and if the control is OK, then the modal popup appears?

Thanks guys.

Comment: anyone ? i dont know how to do

Comment: it's my last problem please help me xD